# How include external css in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a folder called `css` with inside login.css file.
At the same level as this folder, I have login.jsp file. How do I include external css in jsp page?

I tried with

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Login Page </title>
         <link href ="css/login.css" type ="text/css" rel ="stylesheet"></link>
...
```

but it does not work.

If it can be useful in the top login.jsp page is written:

```
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
```

Thanks.

Comment: For one thing you need to get rid of the spaces around the "/" characters, both in the "href" and in the "type".

Comment: Aside from the `</link>` (which will be ignored), you do it like that.

Comment: This is a mistake of copy and paste.
I've updated the question.

Comment: @django Spaces around the `=` matters. Remove that too!

Comment: Done! It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `</link>` tag! Replace like the below:

```
<link href="css/login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

---

Do not give spaces after and before the slashes. Also there's no `</link>` tag! Replace the below:

```
</ title>
         <link href = "css / login.css" type = "text / css" rel = "stylesheet"> </ link>
```

With the below:

```
</title>
         <link href="css/login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: With ' <link href="css/login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> ' doesn't work.

Comment: Is the file `css/login.css` actually exist?

Comment: Yes, it is in css folder. @Praveen Kumar for this reason I can not see where the problem is.

Comment: Try opening it from the browser and let us know what's happening. It might even be a server fault!

Comment: Via the browser with this url: 'http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/css/login.css' it returns 404 error.

Comment: So, the Tomcat server is not able to find the file there. Can you check with your server configuration or something?

Comment: Maybe I have found the problem, css folder is under WEB-INF and css is not visible. Maybe.

Comment: Yes... Try to make it public... :)

Comment: I moved it under webapp folder and it works. Thanks anyway @PraveenKumar.

Answer (score 1):

I have this class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("noughtsandcrosses")
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/pages/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");



        return bean;
    }


    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

for this app structure:

[image]

and import like this:

```
 <link type="text/css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/index.css">
```